# How can I make a text box background color NOT transparent in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I often need to add text to an image. To do this, I use the Text Tool. When I click on the image, I can start filling in the text. However, the box that the text is in always shows up as transparent. There are times where this is good, but many times I want black text on a white box. How can I set the color of the box the text is inside?

Answer (score 0):

You can just bucket fill the layer (no selection) after putting the bucket tool in `Behind` mode. But this makes the text layer no longer a text layer (text and font information is lost).

So a better solution is to add a layer under the text later and bucket-fill, with two options:

- Make a layer the right size (when you create the layer it takes by default the side of the active layer) and bucket-fill the whole layer
- Make an image-size layer, make a rectangle selection and bucket-fill the selection

Note that bucket-filling the text layer (or a layer which is the exact same size) usually won't look good because the boundaries of the layer come from the font geometry (so you can stack/abut layers) and there is a lot more space on top and bottom than on the sides.